# How can i make chunks of a json string in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsstring, nsarray

I am sending a json string from my iphone application to server using ASIFormDataRequest. Sometimes when that string is too big, iphone doesn't send it. request setTimeOutSeconds is 60 seconds. I want to make chunks of my json string when its big and then send those chunks to server. i can not use componentsSepratedByString: method. How can i make an array of substrings of json string. lets say that every substring length should be 200. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSString *longString = <SOME_LONG_STRING>;
NSUInteger chunkSize = 200;

NSMutableArray *chunks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

NSUInteger length = [longString length];
NSUInteger currentPosition = 0;

while (currentPosition < length) {
    NSUInteger thisLength = MIN(chunkSize, length - currentPosition);
    NSString *thisChunk = [longString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(currentPosition, thisLength)];
    [chunks addObject:thisChunk];
    currentPosition += thisLength;
}
```